# How to create Shortcuts on Taskbar and Desktop using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create shortcuts on taskbar and desktop using a python script. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create shortcuts on task bar, the shortcuts need to me placed at:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

and for desktop:

```
C:\Users\user_name\Desktop
```

So here is an example how to do that (Taskbar):

```
import os, winshell , getpass
from win32com.client import Dispatch
loc = 'C:\\Users\\'+ getpass.getuser() +'\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\User Pinned\\TaskBar\\'
loc = os.path.join(loc, "Media Player Classic.lnk")
target = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"
wDir = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic"
icon = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"
shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(loc)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

So here is an example how to do that (Desktop):

```
import os, winshell , getpass
from win32com.client import Dispatch
loc = 'C:\\Users\\'+ getpass.getuser() +'\\Desktop\\'
loc = os.path.join(loc, "Media Player Classic.lnk")
target = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"
wDir = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic"
icon = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"
shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(loc)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua,What about doing shortcut to This PC on desktop and Task bar?

Comment: @isl65 i'll add that too in 5 minutes. dont forget to click the tick mark next to my answer :)

Comment: I tried to do short cut also for 'This PC' which is   explorer top level with out any success

Comment: The command to have this folder is 'explorer.exe = ' How to integrate in your code?

Comment: @isl65 for creating folders, change the taget to the folder location

Comment: @isl65 also the the parent directory in wDir